# Cumulative distribution function (of NHPP inter-arrival time) not tending to 1?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

According to [this website](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr172.htm), for a non-homogeneous Poisson process with mean $m(t) = \int^t_0 \lambda(u) \, dt$, the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the inter-arrival time to the first event is,

$$F_0(t) = 1 - e^{- m(t)}.$$

As $t \rightarrow 0$, $m(t) \rightarrow 0$, so $F_0(t) \rightarrow 1-e^{0} = 1- 1 = 0.$ So that is fine.

However, as $t \rightarrow \infty$, $m(t) \rightarrow \int^{\infty}_0 \lambda(u) \, du$, so $F_0(t) \rightarrow 1 - e^{-\int^{\infty}_0 \lambda(u) \, du}$ which is $1$ only if $\int^{\infty}_0 \lambda(u) \, du$ is $\infty$.

**Question**

Does this mean that the intensity function $\lambda(u)$ of a non-homogeneous Poisson process must be defined such that $m(t) \rightarrow \infty$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$? We cannot have an intensity function that drops to $0$ and remain $0$ after a certain point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit $m(+\infty)$ of $m(t)$ when $t\to+\infty$ is finite, the total number of points is Poisson with parameter $m(+\infty)$, hence there is no point at all with positive probability $\mathrm e^{-m(+\infty)}$. When this happens, there is no first event, in other words the time to wait until the first event is $+\infty$. Hence the defective distribution.

This may happen even when $\lambda(t)\gt0$ for every $t\geqslant0$, and does happen if and only if $\lambda$ is integrable, for example $\lambda(t)=\frac1{1+t^2}$ for every $t\geqslant0$.

Comment: But isn't $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} F(x) = 1$ part of the definition of a CDF? Why is the CDF of the first event waiting time allow to violate this? Or is it wrong to call it a "CDF"?

Comment: I think this answers my comment nicely? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/improper-random-variables